# Dynamically set values into "this" in typescript class constructor

Tags: typescript

Here is a simplified class.
I try to loop over key values in constructor, to dynamically assign values to this. But it doesn't work. Is it a syntax problem ? Or is it not possible ?

```
class DirectoryModel {

    public link_title: string
    public link_desc: string

    constructor(fields: any) {
        console.log(fields) // ok
        _.forOwn(fields, function (value, key) {
            console.log(key) // ok
            console.log(value) // ok
            this[key] = value // "Cannot set property 'link_title' of undefined"
        })

       // this.link_title = fields.link_title
       // this.link_desc = fields.link_desc
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you need the bind that function? Otherwise its `this` will probably be `window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Yasser commented, `this` is not bound to your DirectoryModel. Use [arrow functions](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html) to bind `this` to your instance:

```
class DirectoryModel
{

    public link_title: string
    public link_desc: string

    constructor(fields: any)
    {
        _.forOwn(fields, (value, key) => //This binds `this`
        {
            this[key] = value
        })
    }
}
```